# Cannot add features in OpenLayers 6 in Angular 10

Tags: angular, rxjs, openlayers

I want to display some realtime marks on the map, and I am using ngrx store to get the data, I try to add or change features of the vector layer in an observable, but it doesn't work.

Container component

```
@Component({
selector: "map-container",
template: `
    <ol-map
        id="map"
        [view]="view"
        class="map-container"
        (mapReady)="mapReady($event)"
    >
        <ol-tile-layer
            [source]="tileSource"
            [extent]="extent"
            name="warehouse"
        >
        </ol-tile-layer>
        <ol-vector-layer
            [features]="features$ | async"
        ></ol-vector-layer>
    </ol-map>
`,}
export class MapContainer{ 
   constructor(){
    this.features$ = this.store.select(fromDashboard.selectAllFeatures);
  }
}
```

Vectory Layer Component

```
@Component({
selector: "ol-vector-layer",
template: "",
})
export class OlVectorLayerComponent{
    layer: VectorLayer;
   constructor(){
     this.layer = new VectorLayer({
        source: new VectorSource(),
    });
   }
   @Input("features"){
    set features(data: Feature<Geometry>[]) {
      this.layer.getSource().addFeatures(
       data
    );//this is not working
   }
}
```

I can add features in ngOnInit() function, but cannot add in ngOnChanges() function. Can someone please tell me why addFeatures is not working in ngOnChanges()? Is it because of change detection? I tried adding ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), it was still not working.

Comment: It seems that I cannot use redux store to save feature data, because the state is immutable